# c# WPF WebView2 print pdf without updating UI

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, webview2

I am using a WebView2 control in a WPF application to view PDFs. Printing the currently viewed PDF works fine, however I would like to also be able to print PDFs without the user noticing a change in the UI i.e, use the WebView2 control as a PDF printer.

Is it possible to print a PDF using WebView2 without actually updating the web view UI with it?

Comment: Can you create a WebView2 like normal but hidden in WPF, navigate it to the PDF, and then call the print APIs?

Comment: @DavidRisney Yes this is what I ultimately did, although I don't quite like the solution it seems this feature does not exist in this control.